# Altium Placement Button Unaccessible

Tags: components, altium, component-selection

I'm trying to place a component in Altium from the Manufactur Part Search panel to my schematic, however the place button is greyed out. I can't place my chosen component, or any of its alternatives.

This is what I see:
[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the [manufacturer's documentation?](https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/manufacturer-part-search-panel?version=19.0)

> Component entries listed with an associated  symbol are matched to a corresponding Managed Component in the Altium Content Vault and are therefore ready to be placed in a design.
>
> To restrict the listing to those components that have associated model data, select the Yes option for the Has Model parameter in the Filters pane.